# Polymer 1.0 - paper-textarea autofocusing even when autofocus set to false

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a paper-textarea inside of a drawer. When I go to the page the paper-textarea autofocuses, which opens the drawer. I've tried to get rid of the focus by trying autofocus="false" and autofocus="off", but neither have worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<paper-textarea id="descriptionInput" label="Description" invalid="{{descriptionError}}" error-message="please enter a valid description" value="{{description}}" autofocus="false"></paper-textarea>
```

Update: Another way to go about this might be to remove the focus programatically, but I've tried this.$.descriptionInput.blur() inside of the attached function, and it's not working either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to iron-autogrow-textarea's autofocus property default value being set to "off". The autofocus attribute is active if it exists, the only way to disable it is to remove it all together (ie, autofocus="disabled" or autofocus="off" will still autofocus the tag).

I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-autogrow-textarea/pull/22) and this will hopefully be fixed in future versions.

For the time being, you can create a disabled input tag before the textarea with an autofocus attribute and visibility set to hidden and this will prevent the textarea from gaining focus.

```
<input disabled autofocus style="visibilty: hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with the answer by Kevin Ashcraft, on Safari it was not working.

Here is another option, since the issue it due to the presence of the autofocus attribute, you need to remove that attribute.  So I have polymer element and in there I have the following

```
ready:function(){
    var list = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('iron-autogrow-textarea');
    list.forEach(function (e) {
        e.textarea.removeAttribute("autofocus")
    });
}
```

This scans my dialog, finds all iron-autogrow-textarea and removes the attribute from them... you can change the selector to get only the ones you need.

Update this has been fixed as of latest version Should mention this has been fixed in latest version of https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-autogrow-textarea/releases/tag/v1.0.8